# @PreDestroy method of a Spring singleton bean not called

Tags: spring

I have a Spring bean defined in `beans.xml` as follows:

```
<context:annotation-config />
[...]
<bean id="myBackend" class="mycompany.BackendBean" scope="singleton" />
```

Inside the bean are 2 methods, which must be executed at the start and before termination of the web application:

```
public class BackendBean implements IBackend {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(BackendBean.class);

    @PostConstruct
    public void init()
    {
        LOGGER.debug("init");
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void destroy()
    {
        LOGGER.debug("destroy");
    }
}
```

When I run the server (`mvn jetty:run`), I can see the output of the `init` method in the console, from which I conclude that the `init` method is executed.

When I press `Ctrl-C` and Jetty starts to shut down, I don't see the output of the `destroy` method.

What should I change in order for the `destroy` method to be executed, when the application is terminated?

Comment: Are you planning to run the application on jetty? Or you need to run it in more containers?

Comment: I'm using Jetty for quick tests only. In production, I'm using Apache Tomcat 7.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For Spring to call `@PreDestroy` callback method when you application shuts down, you have to add a shutdown hook and close the application context it in. You could attach the hook to JVM using `Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(Thread)` or to Jetty if it provides such an API. Here is how you'd do it with JVM shutdown hook:

```
final ApplicationContext appContext = ... // create your application context 
                         // using one of the various application context classes
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
   public void run() {
       appContext.close();
   }});
```

Comment: There is `appContext.registerShutdownHook()` for that.

Comment: Thanks. Where (in which method) should I put the shutdown hook registration?

Comment: @DmitriPisarenko The best place would be where you initialize your spring application context.

Comment: @Vitaly Need to elaborate that registerShutDownHook() is a method of AbstractApplicationContext, not of ApplicationContext inteface.

Comment: in case you re-deploy an application, java application doesnt shutdown and hence wont be called.
So, use this if you are using spring-boot or you have disabled redeployment

Comment: appContext.registerShutdownHook() did not work for me. I had to use the provided solution, since it will register shutdown hook to the current JVM instance.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a subtle point you need to be aware of with "prototype" scoped beans.

For "prototype" scoped beans, Spring does not call the @PreDestroy method.

Here is the answer from the Spring official reference manual :

Section 1.5.2 ([see here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#The%20Prototype%20Scope))

> **In contrast to the other scope**s, Spring does not manage the complete
>   lifecycle of a prototype bean**: the container instantiates,
>   configures, and otherwise assembles a prototype object, and hands it
>   to the client, with no further record of that prototype instance.
>
> Thus, although initialization lifecycle callback methods are called on
>   all objects regardless of scope, **in the case of prototypes,
>   configured destruction lifecycle callbacks are not called**. The
>   client code must clean up prototype-scoped objects and release
>   expensive resources that the prototype bean(s) are holding.
>
> To get the Spring container to release resources held by
>   prototype-scoped beans, **try using a custom bean post-processor**, which
>   holds a reference to beans that need to be cleaned up.

**NOTE**: This also applies to XML configuration.

Answer (score 5):

When you use `@Scope("prototype")` in your class @PreDestroy isn't working even though if you try to close with `context.close();` or `context.registerShutdownHook();`

Answer (score 5):

An old question, but wanted to share something I found.

I had a similar piece of code and initially thought that the @PreDestroy method was not being called. But then I added a print statement along with the LOGGER info() and was surprised to see that the print was executed. Apparently it is because the logback shuts itself down even before the @PreDestroy method is being called.

The following source can be useful: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/24431.

Answer (score 1):

Old question but a solution would be to create a class to handle PreDestroy :

```
@Component
public class SetBeanProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor, BeanFactoryAware, DisposableBean {

    private BeanFactory beanFactory;
    private final List<Object> prototypeBeans = new LinkedList<>();

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {

        if (beanFactory.isPrototype(beanName)) {
            synchronized (prototypeBeans) {
                prototypeBeans.add(bean);
            }
        }
        return bean;
    }


    @Override
    public void setBeanFactory(BeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        this.beanFactory = beanFactory;
    }


    @Override
    public void destroy() throws Exception {

        // note : if we have several instance of a prototype (each instance is distinct) the method will be called several times ... 
        synchronized (prototypeBeans) {
            for (Object bean : prototypeBeans) {

                if (bean instanceof DisposableBean) {
                    DisposableBean disposable = (DisposableBean)bean;
                    try {
                        disposable.destroy();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            prototypeBeans.clear();
        }
    }
```

The class that use this class should be implemented this way :

```
@Component
public class myClass implements SomeClassName, DisposableBean {
    ...

    @Override
    public void destroy() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("# myClass: destroy() method called");       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you want `Spring` to take care of this. Unless I misunderstood your question you can go with containers application life cycle.

Try writing a [LifeCycle (jetty)](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/jetty-6/apidocs/org/mortbay/component/LifeCycle.html) and [LifeCycleListener (tomcat)](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/Lifecycle.html) and override in `LifeCyle` `onStart` and `onStop`. And work a similar solution for `LifeCycleListener` in tomcat when the appropriate [event](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/Lifecycle.html#BEFORE_STOP_EVENT) takes place.

Comment: If you do that, you induce a dependency between the shutdown code and the container. It's probably better to avoid it, and keep a single dependency to Spring, which is already there (or even better remove any dependency to Spring and use javax.inject annotations).

Answer (score 0):

You can use method reference "close" for the execution of @PreDestroy methods in Spring:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(applicationContext::close));
```