# Spring Boot - How to register a shutdown hook for a non-GUI application

Tags: java, swing, spring-boot, program-entry-point, shutdown-hook

I am developing an application which is basically a service that will be run with the command line.  I do have an option in the `config` file for it to display a `GUI`.  If the user chooses to have it display the window then I can call my `shutdown()` method using the `WindowClosing` event from Swing or a shutdown button.  However, if the user chooses the no-GUI option, I'm not sure how to ensure this method is called when pressing Control-C in the command prompt.  My `shutdown()` method updates some important data in the database and stops threads so I need it to run.  I have done some research and tried something like this :

```
public static void main(String args[]) 
{
    //Look and Feel Initialization
    try 
    {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) 
        {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) 
            {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } 
    catch (ClassNotFoundException | IllegalAccessException | InstantiationException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) 
    {
        logger.error("Error initializing look and feel : " + ex.getMessage());
    } 

    //Application Initialization
    SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(MDHIS_Service.class);

    application.addListeners((ApplicationListener<ContextClosedEvent>) (ContextClosedEvent e) -> 
    {
        shutdown();
    });

    application.run(args);
}
```

The problem is that my `shutdown()` method is far from static.  I do not know how to wire this into the Spring Boot context to have it run this method before stopping.  I tried the `@PreDestroy` annotation but it does not run the method as expected.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [@PreDestroy method of a Spring singleton bean not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16373276/predestroy-method-of-a-spring-singleton-bean-not-called)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research i ended up implementing the SmartLifecycle interface.  My `getPhase()` method returns `Integer.MAX_VALUE;` which means the bean is destroyed first.  The stop method can then be used to call cleanup code and ensure that any logging / other DB access beans are still alive.

Answer (score 0):

See the [Runtime API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook-java.lang.Thread-) to register a shutdown hook - basically use a Thread to call a method when JVM is terminated (normally or through an interrupt such as CTRL + C).

In this case it looks like `shutdown()` would be a static method within the class which defines `main()`, so something like this:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    ...
    if (using command line) {
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread( () -> shutdown() ));
    }
}
```

Concerning the use of @PreDestroy, this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16373276/predestroy-method-of-a-spring-singleton-bean-not-called) might also help.

Comment: That is my issue, the shutdown method does a lot of things and cannot be called statically.  None of these methods allow that unfortunately.